# How to merge code from my fork to up stream GIT?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I know how to sync my fork from upstream but from my fork changes to upstream merge?

Comment: Search for *"pull request"*.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have write privileges on upstream, you can't just `git push`. You have to publish your changes on your own github fork, then ask upstream for a merge. This is called a *pull request*.

The usual workflow is:

- fork upstream into you own github account/organization (using github web interface)
- clone fork (`git clone https://github.com/my_account/project`)
- add upstream as remote repo (`git remote add upstream https://github.com/upstream/project`)
- work : create branch, modify, commit
- push your changes to your github fork (`git push -u origin my_dev_branch`)
- Create a pull request: when connecting to github web interface right after pushing your dev branch, you should see an option to compare your branch vs. upstream and create a pull request. If you don't see it right away, browse to your dev branch and you should see it.

Note that if you cloned upstream without forking in github (this is what you would have done if you did not intend to contribute when cloning), `origin` points to upstream. You can still fork upstream in github and change your remotes locally like this:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://github.com/my_account/project
```

(You tagged your question github and gitlab. I'm using github in this example but the concepts and most certainly the procedure apply to gitlab just as well.)